# mysql JSON_SET or JSON_INSERT function to insert object into nested object if it exists

Tags: mysql, json, object, mysql-json

I have a json type column `config` I want to add a key value pair into, ultimately looking like:

```
{
  "features": {
    "divisions": true,
    "utilities": {
        "water": true,
        "gas": true,
        "electric": true
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is when I want to insert the utilities object inside of features, I either overwrite the `divisions` key value or I'm returning `NULL` and the `utilities` object isn't being inserted.

Furthermore, the `config` column may be `NULL` or initially just be an empty `{}`.

This query will check for NULL or empty {} and also whether the `features` key exists but results in overwriting `features` if it already exists:

```
UPDATE entities SET config = JSON_SET(COALESCE(config, '{}'),
  COALESCE("$.features", "features"), JSON_OBJECT("utilities", 
  JSON_OBJECT("water", TRUE, "gas", TRUE, "electric", TRUE))) 
  WHERE id = 123725082;
```

This works fine unless the column already contains something like:

```
{
  "features": {
    "divisions": true,
  }
}
```

in which it overwrites `divisions` with the `utilities` object.

So I'm trying a JSON_INSERT query; from what I've gathered from mysql json functions documentation should work but it's returning null and I can't understand why:

```
UPDATE entities SET config = JSON_INSERT(COALESCE(config, '{}'),
  COALESCE("$.features", "features"), JSON_OBJECT("utilities", 
  JSON_OBJECT("water", TRUE, "gas", TRUE, "electric", TRUE))) 
  WHERE id = 123725082;
```

Comment: What's the point of `COALESCE("$.features", "features")`? It's the same as just `"$.features"`.

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with the full expression, but I think you need a mix of `JSON_EXTRACT` and `COALESCE` calls to handle missing properties at each level of the JSON structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSON_MERGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge) function can be useful in this case.

Modify the `UPDATE` as needed:

```sql
UPDATE `entities`
  SET `config` = COALESCE(
    JSON_MERGE(
      `config`,
      JSON_OBJECT('features',
        JSON_OBJECT('utilities',
          JSON_OBJECT('water', TRUE, 'gas', TRUE, 'electric', TRUE)
        )
      )
    ),
    JSON_INSERT(
      JSON_OBJECT(),
      '$.features',
       JSON_OBJECT('utilities',
         JSON_OBJECT('water', TRUE, 'gas', TRUE, 'electric', TRUE)
       )
    )
  );
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xbUUxasA1BYB5wXyJLZaQp/1).

Comment: The fiddle helped me out quite a bit to figure out these methods, thanks :)